# Can you use @model like @ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model, viewbag

So I have a question about `model` in ASP.NET MVC. I know I can use a ViewBag like this: `<h1> @ViewBag.Question </h1>` and it would display the text in `@ViewBag.Question`. Can I use `@model` in the same way? I have tried using it in the same context, `<h1> @Model.Question </h1>` but the view throws an error. How can I display the text of a `model` property inside an html element?

Comment: İf your model has a property for Question then you can .What is the error meanwhile?

Comment: I'm a moron, I forgot to actually pass the model to the view. I just assumed because I was trying something new it was that that broke it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `@Model` can be used in the same way as `@ViewBag`